# How does the LC circuit work in a FM transmitter circuit

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, oscillator, frequency-modulation

I am using  a app called Every Circuit. I dont understand how does the LC circuit function i know that it produces a sine wave but in that case both side of the lC circuit capacitor are connected at the same side so how does it work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by at the same side?

Comment: @Andyaka from what i observe the current will flow on both side of VC1  as the inductor allows the current to flow back to the + side of the battery while on the other side current also flows from the transistor to the capacitor. So whats the point of the capacitor? I dont really understand how fm circuit works

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  at VC1 current flows from the transistor to the capacitor and current alsk flows from the inductor to the other side of the capacitor

Comment: user151005, I don't wish to be mean but honestly, it seems likely to me that your grasp of electric circuit fundamentals is not strong enough to tackle a circuit like this.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  sorry my knowledge of understanding circuits arent good enough as im not really attending any lesson as its more of a hobby for me. But could you explain what i missed out?

Comment: user151005, oscillator circuits, like this one, are difficult enough to analyze, challenging to simulate, and nearly impossible to explain to one with a limited background in theory.  This circuit has positive feedback at some frequency determined in part by the the capacitor across the inductor (which is why it's variable - to adjust the frequency of oscillation).

Comment: @AlfredCentauri possible if we use a crystal oscillator instead?

Answer (score 2):

Oscillator:
The tank circuit (mainly  L1 and VC1) ressonates   in the 100 MHz region. At this frequency (RF) the base of Q1 is grounded and the transistor is in a  common-base configuration. C2 and R2 are a voltage divider providing (nearly) positive RF feedback through the emitter-base voltage, maintaining oscillations.  C2 is also in parallel with the tank at RF, affecting the nominal carrier frequency.

Modulator: 
This is a reactance modulator based on Q1's collector-base capacitance (Cbc or another datasheet symbol), not shown in the circuit. Cbc is also effectivelly in parallel with the tank at RF. This capacitance  is modulated by the audio input  (due to  Q1's base voltage fluctuations caused by the modulating signal),  leading to the FM modulation of the oscillator.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You schematic does not contain an LC (capacitor and inductor in series or in parallel) circuit. The signal source is a sine wave generator on the left side of the schematic.

If you are simply interested in LC circuits, first get a good understanding of how a capacitor and how an inductor functions. Then start to read about LC resonant circuits.

Edit:

The OP has edited the original question to include a schematic that is unrelated to the originally provided simulation circuit on which I based the above response.

If the newly supplied schematic even works, its FM capabilities would be marginal. The variable capacitor shown would set the carrier frequency - assuming the LC tank circuit would oscillate. It appears the design is targeting around 450 MHz using mid band values.

I suspect the circuit would generate a stronger AM component if anything at all. Whenever I see a variable capacitor specified as 0 to 100 pF, I consider the knowledge of the designer to be dubious.

Comment: For down voters, please notice that this answer was a response to the original post (before first edit), which did not have an inductor in the schematic

Comment: In fact, it is a completely different schematic from the simulation. Grrr...

Comment: I've withdrawn my downvote. Bloody op posting crap and amending it without a freaking care in the world to answers given. Guess which button I'm gonna press now.