# Circuit parts identification (simple FM transmitter)

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol1l3.png]

I try to identify 'parts' of this circuit, I learn with the Internet and I start the electronics since a few time. I try to know the location of each 'type' (LC, RC, LRC etc ...) on this simplest FM transmitter found on makezine. Also, I'm learning with falstad but I do not understand the starting point of identifying the 'parts'. I create this schema with my questions .Thank for your help and your time.

[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The parts shown are ideal yet ESR is not included. You can try a wire antenna using the transmission line at 240 ohms more or less which depends on wire thickness as inductance of ~0.5nH/mm on a 1/4 wave monopole of a 1/2 wave dipole or staggered dipole Yagi gives increasing high gain . But you cannot use a simple LC lumped circuit or a transmission line  to simulate on an unbuffered resonator as it lowers the output resonant f

Comment: @PlasmaHH My question is how to identify parts of circuit.thank.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, Thank you very much for this important note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C1 + R1 = [high pass filter](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_3.html) (3 .. 100 hz/33uF..1uF)

C2 = RF decoupling for Q1 base (RF shortcircuit)

C3 = also a decoupling capacitor, no other specific function.

R2 = base polarization for Q1

L1, C4 , C5 and Q1 BE and CB capacitance - series LC resonant circuit.

There is a similar question answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308855/how-does-the-lc-circuit-work-in-a-fm-transmitter-circuit)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, that's the answer I was waiting for, how i can calculate Q1 BE capacitance or resonance frequency please ?

Comment: @f14284 BE capacitance from the datasheet Ceb0 = 18pf https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/2N3904.pdf Total capacitance can be calculated from the configuration: C4 parallel with ( C5 series with Ceb ) . Total resonant capacitance   Ctot = C4 + C5*Ceb/(C5+Ceb)

Comment: Thank you very much , I searched desperately. If I use your formula I get an LC serie resonance at 189.936MHz for : Ctot = 16.4pf and the 4 Turns solenoid air coil inductance 42.74nH (If I just for the calculation of the coil, this is my related first post: [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375225/understand-simple-fm-transmitter-inductance-resonance))  This is an FM transmitter and my calculated frequency is out FM range. Do you know what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks again.

Comment: @f14284 Something is really wrong then, for 70 MHz the equivalent capacitance would be 120 pf !!! It's way to far.

Comment: thanks again for your time, yes for the signal found on ~70MHz with my RTL-SDR, I think my C4 and C5 values are bad, I use C4 trim cap: 4 to 25 pf (100%) and C5 trim cap. : 2 to 6pf (50%) and I measure this capacity with my arduino capacimeter, but I think I'm wrong for that and, also, my coil is not equal to the original scheme but my calculations refer to the original scheme in all cases. So either I calculate poorly the inductance of my coil, or I miss something.

Comment: @f14284 Most likely the capacimeter shows a greater value than the real one. I' m not sure what is your purpose, to show the theory behind or to build a real working thing. If you just want to make-it work than increase the coil turn until you're close then use the trimmers to get the right frequency.

Comment: I am trying to understand how it works both in theory and in practice. I will want to calculate the signal transmission frequency of this circuit, to be able to precisely adjust the set and understand how radio waves are created from a circuit (mainly the out RF frequency). But I'm not sure that my calculations are good and that's why I thank you for your help because you help me a lot

Comment: @f14284 I will try a simulation later to see which is to blame, the real setup or the theory.

Comment: what I do not understand is that on the blog where the project is located, nobody in the comments made the calculations precisely (inductance of coil is not specified). It takes experience and some concepts I can see, but I want to take the time to learn them. Thank's again. and sorry i have not a good reputation here for the moment for up-vote your answer.

Comment: @f14284 The spice simulation shows 150Mhz , less than it should but still close. Check coil and capacitors value.

Comment: @f14284 The 150MHz is realistic taking into account the CB capacitance of 4 pF at 10V  but here the CB voltage is lower so the capacitance higher, and also B3 capacitance is given at 0.5V but here BE voltage is higher so the BE capacitance is higher ( the BE junction is forward biased, the capacitance increases with the voltage ). For 150MHz total capacitance is 26.5 pf

Comment: thank you for this return but what is the inductance you use for the calculation? I will re-try all the calculations.

Comment: @f14284 42nH , all values from your schematic. You must also find CB and EB capacitance by CB and EB voltage to get precise calculations. I don't think you can since their value is not guaranteed in the datasheet

Comment: thank again , ok but i do not know if my inductance calculation is good because some include the wire diameter in the formula and others do not. With the diameter of the wire I find: `55.85 nh` and without the wire diameter `42.74 nh`, which can change the whole result. I think I will reopen a post dedicated to this question , but I have already done so and no one has answered me [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375225/understand-simple-fm-transmitter-inductance-resonance).

Comment: @f14284 It doesn't change the result so much,.The errer in frequency is less than 10% from 55.2 to 42.7.nH. It's not so bad. You will never get better than that from the first shoot, Just adjust your capacitors or coil to the desired frequency.